# Select data in array between start and end date

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, date

I have script that show markers on heatmap

Here is script

```
    function getDriving() {
    markers.length = 0;
    var todayval = new Date();
    var url = $('#map').data('request-url2');
    $.getJSON(url,
        function (data) {
            $.each(data,
                function (i, item) {

                    markers.push({
                        'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
                        'map': map,
                        'weight': item.Speed,
                        'radius': 10,
                        'date': item.CurrentDateTime,
                        'imei': item.Imei
                    });
                });

            $.each(markers, function (i, marker) {
                var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
                var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));
                console.log(markerDate);
                if (markerDate.getDate() === todayval.getDate()) {
                    todaymarkersfiltered.push(marker);
                }
            });
            var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(todaymarkersfiltered);
            console.log(pointArray);
            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: pointArray
            });
            heatmap.setMap(map);
        });
};
```

In View I have startDate and EndDate

Now I filter only by startDate.

Here is script

```
 filtered.length = 0;
$('#filter').on('click',
    function () {
        heatmap.setMap(null);
        var startValue = $('#startDate').val().split("/");
        $.each(markers, function (i,marker) {
            var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
            var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));
            var valDate = new Date(startValue[2], startValue[1] - 1, startValue[0]);
            if (markerDate.getDate() === valDate.getDate() && (marker.imei === imei || imei === null)) {
                filtered.push(marker);
            } 
        });
        var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(filtered);
        console.log(pointArray);
        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);

    }); //filtering by date and imei code of device
```

But how I can filter data between start and end date.

SO for example I have start date 11/14/2017 and end date 11/16/2017. I need to show all data where `markerDate` in this range. end data will be taken from input too. Like this `var endValue = $('#endDate').val().split("/");`

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [**`.filter()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do this:

```
var startValue = new Date($('#startDate').val());
var endValue = new Date($('#endDate').val());

var filtered = markers.filter(function(marker) {
  var markerDate = new Date(marker.date);
  return (markerDate > startValue && markerDate < endValue);
});
```

Comment: you mean write this instead of 
`$.each(markers, function (i,marker) {
                var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
                var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));
                var valDate = new Date(startValue[2], startValue[1] - 1, startValue[0]);
                if (markerDate.getDate() === valDate.getDate() && (marker.imei === imei || imei === null)) {
                    filtered.push(marker);
                } 
            });`?

Comment: @S.E Yes, that's it. It should filter it automatically.

Comment: Also it will push results to filtered automatically by return?

Comment: @S.E yes exactly, that's it.